# Intellij, cucumber test and two spring Context Configuration

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, cucumber

My project has two different cucumber test and each one needs a different spring context configuration.

The problem I have is that when I run each test individually from  Intellij, they load the right Spring Context and the tests are passing, but I press run all test, none of them are passing.

Running a maven test, both test are passing.

this is my code:

```js
@RunWith(FCSCucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(strict = true
//        , tags = {"~@ignore"}
//        , tags = {"@Only"}
        , glue ="feature.scenario1"
        , features = "src/test/resources/feature/scenario1/"
)
@FCSApplicationProperties(commonProps="config/scenario1/exec.common.properties",
        environmentProps="src/test/resources/scenario1-test.properties")
public class TesScenario1Features {
 
}
```

```js
@ContextConfiguration("/cucumber-scenario1.xml")
public class scenario1Steps {
......
}
```

```js
@RunWith(FCSCucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(strict = true
//        , tags = {"~@ignore"}
//        , tags = {"@Only"}
        , glue ="feature.scenario2"
        , features = "src/test/resources/feature/scenario2/"
)
@FCSApplicationProperties(commonProps="config/scenario2/exec.common.properties",
        environmentProps="src/test/resources/scenario2-test.properties")
public class TesScenario2Features {
 
}
```

```js
@ContextConfiguration("/cucumber-scenario2.xml")
public class scenario2Steps {
......
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the [IntelliJ cucumber plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/5d75d0e6425f5a290bbddf9baad72d1d4cb2810a/cucumber-java/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/cucumber/java/run/CucumberJavaRunConfigurationProducer.java) is using the [cucumber cli](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/19fd08e97b78b5a33149cd6338a2f5ef244a8d7f/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) to run tests, without using the JUnit runner at all. This causes several limitations, like requiring the spring annotations on the step definition classes instead of the runner, or by default requiring the steps definitions to be in the same package as the scenario files.

In your example I would actually expect also running a single test to fail, unless the correct application properties are also referenced by the `/cucumber-scenario{1,2}.xml` files.

The only option I see with the standard cucumber implementation would be to extract the tests into separate projects.

I'm actually working on an [alternative implementation of cucumber](https://github.com/jhorstmann/zuchini) with an improved spring integration that you might want to try. It's not fully integrated with IntelliJ yet though.